# GraphQL mutation Invalid payload

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have the following mutation

```
mutation createFoo {
    createFoo(data: {title: "Test"}) {
        foo {
            id
            title
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran I got the error

> AssertionError: 'errors' unexpectedly found in ['errors', 'data'] : {'errors': [{'message': 'Invalid payload', 'locations': [{'line': 3, 'column': 17}], 'path': ['createFoo']}], 'data': {'createFoo': None}}

What can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this mutation defined in your *typeDefs*? If you have:

```
mutation createFoo(title: String!): foo
```

then you need to invoke it with:

```
mutation createFoo {
    createFoo(title: "Test") {
        id
        title
    }
}
```

If on the other hand you have:

```
mutation createFoo(data: {title: String!}): foo
```

(which would be weird) then you need to invoke it with:

```
mutation createFoo {
    createFoo(data: {title: "Test"}) {
        id
        title
    }
}
```

One of the other or both of *data:* in the input or *foo {…}* in the output are likely redundant.

Comment: Why the second why is weird? I thought it is better. I am new on GraphQL

Comment: The `data` is unnecessary/redundant as you can define the parameters to the query/mutation directly. Otherwise you need an additional level of destructuring in your server code.